# Curve Start/End Mapping linked animation can't be made Single User

Tags: animation, bezier-curves

I have several curves which need to be animated.

I animated the Start End Mapping for the first one, and then by CTRL + L linked the animation to the others. I then tried to make each other curve animation single user, but the Start End Mapping is still linked to the first curve.

Is this a limit, or there’s another way to make the Start End Mapping single user?

[example](https://mega.nz/file/DSwywBQA#oh5zf0KoQFEpWmQ3yKAWusYSyMcc9ivof7y9QKNXqdo)

Comment: what you could do is use the NLA editor and push down both actions -> then you can seperate both

Comment: Thanks, Chris. That's a good workaround. How do I mark your answer as a solution? I can only up vote it (which I did).

Comment: i wrote an answer for it. Now you can mark it ;) you are welcome and thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the NLA editor, push down both actions -> then you can separate both.

[image]